# Inverse Fourier transform problem

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Can anybody please guide me how to compute the following inverse Fourier Transform ?

$$ p(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-j\omega\bar{x})^K}e^{-j\omega x}d\omega $$

I shall be grateful.

Comment: Is the bar on the $x$ intentional, is $x$ complex? Is $K\ge 1$ assumed? Did you try the residuum method of complex analysis for this type of integrals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any polynomials $P$ and $Q$ with $\deg Q\ge 1+\deg P$ and $\alpha>0$ one has

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}e^{i αx}\,dx=2\pi i\sum_{z:Q(z)=0\,\land\, Im(z)α>0}Res\left(x\mapsto\tfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}e^{i αx},z\right)$$

where $Res(f,z)$ is the residue of $f$ in $z$, i.e., developing $f(z+w)$ as Laurent series in $w$ it is the coefficient of the power $w^{-1}$.

This is mentioned, but not in detail, in the wikipedia article on contour integration.

The idea is to integrate along a box over the interval $[-R,R]$ where the part of the sides gets smaller with larger $R$ due to the degree difference and the part of the top side gets smaller for increasing height because $|e^{i αz}|=e^{-α\, Im(z)}$.

Increasing the size $R$ of the box to infinity reduces the contour integal to the integral over the real line. Going the other way by shrinking the contour over the region of holomorphy allows by the Cauchy integral theorem to reduce the contour integral to integrals along small circles around the singularities, whose values are given by the residues of the singularities, times $2\pi i$.

If $α>0$ one has to take the residues of the upper half plane, for $α<0$ the residues of the lower half plane.

---

In your case with the different variable names the integration variable is $ω$, $P(ω)=1$, $Q(ω)=(1-jω\bar x)^K$ with a root at $ω_0=-j\bar x^{-1}$. Inserting $ω=ω_0+\zeta$ one gets $Q(ω_0+\zeta)=(-j ζ\bar x)^K$ and

$$f(ω)=\frac1{2\pi}\frac{e^{-jxω}}{(1-jω\bar x)^K}=\frac1{2\pi}e^{-jxω_0}\frac{1+(-jxζ)+...+\tfrac1{n!}(-jxζ)^n+...}{(-j ζ\bar x)^K}$$

so that residue, the coefficient for $ζ^{-1}$, is obtained for the term $n=K-1$ of the exponential series in the numerator, that is

$$Res(f,ω_0)=\frac{j}{2\pi}e^{-\tfrac{x}{\bar x}}\frac{x^{K-1}}{(K-1)!\bar x^K}$$.

For $\bar x>0$ we get the only singularity $ω_0$ in the lower half plane. With $α=-x$ this means that the integral is only different from zero if $x>0$ so that $α<0$. And vice versa, for $\bar x<0$ non-trivial values of the integral are only possible for $x>0$.

This gives the value of the integral as

$$2\pi j\,Res(f,ω_0)=-e^{-\tfrac{x}{\bar x}}\frac{x^{K-1}}{(K-1)!\bar x^K}$$

whenever $x$ and $\bar x$ have the opposite sign.

Comment: I am sorry this is a bit difficult to understand. The answer to the above integral is $$ p(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(K)\bar{x}^K} x^{K-1}e^{-x/\bar{x}} $$ I donot understand how did gamma entered the equation ? I am thankful for your time

Comment: $Γ(K)=(K-1)!$ if $K$ is an integer. If not the derivation may become more conmplicated.

Comment: Wow @LutzL This is great! please give me a minute to digest your explanantion :) as it is hard to understand and i will get back to you if i donot understand anything. I am really grateful to you for your efforts and help

Comment: K is an integer

Comment: I did not understand the step where you set $\omega = \omega_0 + \zeta $ what does $\zeta$ represents ? and i didnot get <<so that the coefficient for $\zeta^{-1}$ ...>> either.

Comment: One needs to develop the integrand as a Laurent series as one method of computing the residue. One can write the Laurent series in terms of powers of $(ω-ω_0)$ or shorter in terms of powers of $ζ=(ω-ω_0)$. When integrating around a singularity, the only term of the Laurent series that contributes a nontrivial integral is the term of $ζ^{−1}$, it is the only remainder, left-over, of this contour integration, the residue.

Comment: Still a bit difficult for me but Thankyou very much for your excellent explanation and guidance. That is really helpful.

Comment: Yes, it is not clear to me too if I did some sign error somewhere. Does your solution also tell you that the result is zero if $x$ and $\bar x$ have the same sign?

Comment: No, it does not say anything regarding the signs of $x$ and $\bar{x}$. In my case $\bar{x}$ is the mean value of $x$. Please let me know if you find any error.

Comment: I have reworked the computation, some signs have changed, it is hopefully now more correct.

Comment: Once again thankyou very much LutzL. You are great :)